# Use an usb printer from an Android device

Tags: usb, printing

I have an old usb printer and I'm wondering if it's possible to use it to print from an Android device.

I'm thinking a micro-usb-to-usb adapter and then just plug it in... Will it work? If not out of the box, how simple is it?

Answer (score 3):

It likely wont. Because two things:

1) **Drivers:** Android wont know how to operate that printer. All ends here.

2) Even if printer has some Gandalf's spell to be detected by android, AFAIK android doesn't have a mechanism to pass out binary pixel data to printer to print the image.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options out there, here is a good article detailing them -
[Everything You Need to Know About Printing From your Android Phone or Tablet](http://www.howtogeek.com/165778/everything-you-need-to-know-about-printing-from-your-android-phone-or-tablet/)

Personally, I've had some luck with my old printer using an OTG cable and the PrintShare app. It seems to have a good library of drivers.

[PrintShare - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamixsoftware.printershare):

Answer (score 0):

I would plug the USB printer into a nearby computer and enable network sharing, meaning you should be able to find a way to print from your Android; I use Google's cloud print app to print from my my phone to a shared network printer.

As for a direct connection between the printer and the Android, I don't think it's possible.